# List all methods related to a model which scaffold creates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, frameworks, scaffolding, scaffold

Is there a way to list all methods which **scaffold** creates regarding **Ruby on Rails**?

Example:

> rails generate scaffold user name:string admin:references

Now, within the controller, the following declaration is possible:

```
@user = User.new 
@user.admin=current_admin
```

Now, I want to check where the **admin() method** comes from - or where it is placed respectively.

I tried to figure out that topic with the help of the following book:
Michael Hartl - Ruby on Rails Tutorial Learn Web Development with Rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this snippet to find where a specific method is defined (`User#admin=`) in your case:

```
User.instance_method(:admin=).source_location
```

And it will likely return something like this, depending on your Ruby and Ruby on Rails version:

```
["[...]/3.2.0/gems/activerecord-7.0.6/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb", 111]
```

Which will tell you that it is a method auto-generated by Ruby on Rails for an association.

The next step would then be to look into the source code of `User` for a defined association like `belongs_to :admin`.